# Cannot iterate over map whose elements hold a uniq_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

The following code fails to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct HaveUniq {
    std::unique_ptr<int> uniq;
};

void print_hus(const std::map<int, HaveUniq>& hus) {
    for (const std::pair<int, HaveUniq>& p: hus)
        std::cout << *p.second.uniq << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, HaveUniq> hus;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        hus[i].uniq = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(i));
    print_hus(hus);
}
```

With the following error:

```
uniq_wtf.cpp: In function ‘void print_hus(const std::map<int, HaveUniq>&)’:
uniq_wtf.cpp:10:42: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 
‘const std::pair<int, HaveUniq>&’ from expression of type
‘const std::pair<const int, HaveUniq>’
for (const std::pair<int, HaveUniq>& p: hus)
```

So, it tries to iterate over values rather than constant references, and it cannot coerce those values into references.

It is clear that an objects that has a unique_ptr as one of its fields cannot have a default copying constructor. But if I understand correctly, iterating over a map doesn't involve copying, so it shouldn't be a problem.
Or does the map iterator actually copy the values?
And why would it have problem with coercing values to references?

By the way, the code works if the unique_ptr is replaced with simple integer, and if the map is replaced with std::array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compiler error is very clear. `std::map::value_type` is actually `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, so just this make your code works:

```
for (const std::pair<const int, HaveUniq>& p: hus)
```

or just

```
for (const auto& p : hus)
```

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EbDhaJMeRANYYA9h)

Comment: That works! I overlooked that const. But why does this error happen only when the value type has unique_ptr as a field?

Comment: @MichaelIvko ehm... Have no idea why.

Comment: Your solution fixes the problem, but it is still rather curious: If `HaveUniq::uniq` is anything other than a `unique_ptr`, the original code compiles just fine. Why does it _not_ work for `unique_ptr`, when it works for other member types?

Comment: @MichaelIvko because in this case compiler fails to make a copy when trying to initialize std::pair<int, HaveUniq> with std::pair<const int, HaveUniq>

Comment: @mindriot: `std::pair<int, int> p = std::pair<const int, int>(..)` is legal, so you got (dangling) reference to temporary pair construct from the real one.

Comment: @Jarod42 yep, correct. Thanks :) But I was faster than you, see my answer :)

Comment: @Jarod42 it isn't dangling; reference lifetime extension applies.

Answer (score 6):

ForEveR's answer shows how to solve your problem, yet it does not completely explain *why* you have that problem in the first place.  Thing is, it only occurs with `unique_ptr`.  So let's look into it a bit more.  I wrote this test program:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct Foo { std::string bar; };
struct Bar { std::unique_ptr<int> bar; };

int main()
{
  std::map<int, Foo> mfoo;
  mfoo[23] = Foo { "foo" };
  for (const auto& foo : mfoo) { }
  for (const std::pair<const int, Foo>& foo : mfoo) { }
  for (const std::pair<int, Foo>& foo : mfoo) { }

  std::map<int, Bar> mbar;
  mbar[23].bar = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42));
  for (const auto& bar : mbar) { }
  for (const std::pair<const int, Bar>& bar : mbar) { }
  for (const std::pair<int, Bar>& bar : mbar) { }       // <-- FAILS

  return 0;
}
```

Everything works, but as in your example, only the marked line fails. In my case, the compiler error is a bit more helpful though:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20:41: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘std::pair<const int, Bar>’ to ‘const std::pair<int, Bar>&’ [-fpermissive]
   for (const std::pair<int, Bar>& bar : mbar) { }
                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:150:12: note: candidate is: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = const int; _U2 = Bar; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _T1 = int; _T2 = Bar] <near match>
  constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)
            ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:150:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<const int, Bar>’ to ‘std::pair<const int, Bar>&&’
test.cpp:20:41: error: cannot bind ‘std::pair<const int, Bar>’ lvalue to ‘std::pair<const int, Bar>&&’
   for (const std::pair<int, Bar>& bar : mbar) { }
                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:150:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = const int; _U2 = Bar; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _T1 = int; _T2 = Bar]’
  constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)
```

What we can gather from this: Because the requested type `std::pair<int, Bar>` does not *exactly* match the actual returned type that has a **`const`**`int`, it needs to create a copy.  And it can't do that with a `unique_ptr`.

That's why we get the complaint about the compiler not being able to bind the `pair` to an `lvalue`.