# Iterate map<string, unique_ptr<Foo> >

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr, stdmap

I see there exists a very close Q/A here: [Iterating over a container of unique_ptr's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237502/iterating-over-a-container-of-unique-ptrs)
However when it involves iteration of map, I do not see how to avoid copy/assignment of the unique_ptr.

When I iterate the map, e.g., using c++17 for simplicity, assuming x is a public member variable of int type for Foo:

```
map<string, unique_ptr<Foo> > my_map;
for (auto const& [key, val] : my_map) {
  val->x = 1;
}
```

I got the error:

```
constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<Foo>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

I do see another post ([Cannot iterate over map whose elements hold a uniq_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064362/cannot-iterate-over-map-whose-elements-hold-a-uniq-ptr/35064887)) doing:

```
map<string, wrapper_struct > my_map;
```

where wrapper_struct is a struct with unique_ptr inside.  My question is: are there any simpler solutions?

Comment: [Works just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f00b84ba1308f25e).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a const reference to the iterator itself instead of the elements in the pair.

```
for (const auto& it : my_map) {
    auto ptr_to_unique_foo = it.second.get();
}
```

Comment: I wrote a simpler test code and your method works. So it's other errors, might be related to my special Foo class. Digging ...

Comment: There is no need to use a const reference to an iterator. The iterator itself will do just fine. You have a const reference to a stored *value*, not to an iterator, which is fine too.